# Error: No component factory found for GoogleCardLayout2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 with Angular 6 template app and I am trying to redirect the user to another page(on click). I keep getting this error message

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for GoogleCardLayout2. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for GoogleCardLayout2. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError
```

and I am not sure what it means. In my ".ts" file I imported the second page

```
import { GoogleCardLayout2 } from '../layout-2/google-card-layout-2';
```

and also set a function to push the user to the next page

```
openTestpage() {

        this.navCtrl.push(GoogleCardLayout2);

    }
```

But I just keep running into the error. Here is my html, ts and module code

**HTML**

```
<div watch-now text-center (click)="openTestpage()">
                    <button ion-button button-icon icon-start>
                        <ion-icon icon-small [name]="item.icon"></ion-icon>
                        {{item.iconText}}
                    </button>

                </div>
```

**TS file**

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, Content, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleCardLayout2 } from '../layout-2/google-card-layout-2';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'google-card-layout-1',
    templateUrl: 'google-card.html'

})
export class GoogleCardLayout1 {
    @Input() data: any;
    @Input() events: any;
    @ViewChild(Content)
    content: Content;
    slider = {};


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {


    }

    openTestpage() {

        this.navCtrl.push(GoogleCardLayout2);

    }
}
```

**Module TS file**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleCardLayout1 } from './google-card-layout-1';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        GoogleCardLayout1,

    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(GoogleCardLayout1),
    ],
    exports: [
        GoogleCardLayout1
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class GoogleCardLayout1Module { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { AppSettings } from '../services/app-settings'
import { ToastService } from '../services/toast-service'
import { LoadingService } from '../services/loading-service'

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(AppSettings.FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [MyApp],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    StatusBar, SplashScreen,
    ToastService, LoadingService,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**GoogleCardLayout2 Module**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleCardLayout2 } from './google-card-layout-2';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        GoogleCardLayout2,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(GoogleCardLayout2),
    ],
    exports: [
        GoogleCardLayout2
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class GoogleCardLayout2Module { }
```

Comment: hey welcome to SO. Can you share you app.module.ts? and also - are you using lazy loading for page/components or not?

Comment: I am using a template I found on a website so I am not sure if they did or did not and yes I can

Answer (score 0):

The error means pretty much what it says - you need to add it to entryComponent in your GoogleCardLayout2Module module. Do not make any changes to your GoogleCardLayout1Module. In your GoogleCardLayout2Module, you need to include GoogleCardLayout2 like this:

```
// import GoogleCardLayout2 above
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        GoogleCardLayout2
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        GoogleCardLayout2
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: I get this message when I do that "Error: Type GoogleCardLayout2 is part of the declarations of 2 modules: GoogleCardLayout1Module and GoogleCardLayout2Module! Please consider moving GoogleCardLayout2 to a higher module that imports GoogleCardLayout1Module and GoogleCardLayout2Module. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes GoogleCardLayout2 then import that NgModule in GoogleCardLayout1Module and GoogleCardLayout2Module."

Comment: ok, I didn't realize there were another module. Remove it completely from GoogleCardLayout1Module, then make sure to include it in the `entryComponents` array in GoogleCardLayout2Module (the same way as shown in my answer).

Comment: I am sorry, remove and include what? Can you update your answer so I can view what you mean?

Comment: And here is a screenshoot of my directory just in case you get confused https://gyazo.com/90e1b8795f4e38c14064dc89b4022f79

Comment: I did that and It's not working. Can you help me on team viewer?

Comment: sorry, I'm not doing teamviewer. But if you haven't lost hope yet I'll still try to help as best I can here :) Can you please update your question with your current GoogleCardLayout2Module? And if you got a different error after your changes, please include that too. Or even better, if you can create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) of your entire project, it would be 100x easier to help.

Comment: I add the layout 2 module and I wish I can do stackBlitz but I bought the template app so its a lot of files and I am not sure which to add and which not to

Comment: Try adding GoogleCardLayout2 to the entryComponents array in your GoogleCardLayout2Module like shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So yes pretty much the issue is that you need to include your GoogleCardLayout2 component into a module.

Looking at your code below I conclude GoogleCardLayout2 is NOT lazy loaded (since otherwise you would use 'string' vs Component in the push method:

```
openTestpage() {

    this.navCtrl.push(GoogleCardLayout2);

}
```

This means you can import this Component into your app's module and add it into the entryComponents:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { AppSettings } from '../services/app-settings'
import { ToastService } from '../services/toast-service'
import { LoadingService } from '../services/loading-service'

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

//import your non-lazy loaded module here but check the path!:
import { GoogleCardLayout2 } from '../layout-2/google-card-layout-2';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    // also add this:
    GoogleCardLayout2
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(AppSettings.FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  // now add your component here:
  entryComponents: [MyApp, GoogleCardLayout2],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    StatusBar, SplashScreen,
    ToastService, LoadingService,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

If you would decide to turn your GoogleCardLayout2 into a lazy loaded module, the approach will be different. You would need to create a module inside its folder first, then import that created module into GoogleCardLayout1's module. If you could share GoogleCardLayout1's module file I can help add code for that.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work because the app.module.ts is not in the same file directory ass my "googlecardlayout.ts". Here is a screenshoot of my directory and you can see "app.module" is in the app folder and the google card layout is under "components" https://gyazo.com/90e1b8795f4e38c14064dc89b4022f79

Comment: It will work you just need to use proper import path for the layout2. Did you try it? Or do you struggle to understand what this path is?

Comment: Yes I did. The path was correct but I still get an error. I am just giving the path to the .ts correct?

Comment: Message I get "Type GoogleCardLayout2 is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and GoogleCardLayout1Module! Please consider moving GoogleCardLayout2 to a higher module that imports AppModule and GoogleCardLayout1Module. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes GoogleCardLayout2 then import that NgModule in AppModule and GoogleCardLayout1Module"

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention - after you did as in my answer you need to remove layout 2 from GoogleCardLayout1Module

Comment: You need to go to google-card-layout-1.module.ts and remove reference to GoogleCardLayout2 from it. You didn't share your full code so I don't know your project's structure ;/

Comment: So would add my java-script in the module file?

Comment: No you just need to go the the file google-card-layout-1.module.ts and remove import statement and entryComponent for your layout 2

Comment: I did and i get this "Component GoogleCardLayout2 is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."

Comment: OK so now do you have it (GoogleCardLayout2) imported AND added as entryComponent in your app's app.module.ts. Also I realized you need to add it into "declarations part as well. I will update my answer

Comment: sorry its like searching for something in a dark room. Ideally you shoud upload your code to stackblitz or something